# How to calculate the flight route distance using Cirium API

Tags: api

I wish to calculate the distance covered by a flight from one airport to another using CIRIUM API. But unable to find the appropriate API endpoint. Is there any way to get this?

I've triend various API endpoints from the CIRIUM API references:
https://developer.flightstats.com/api-docs/#quickref

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

CIRIUM doesn't support distance calculation or distance information any more. I've asked to support, and they have confirmed this.